# FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread, StackOverflowError with Google maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am implementing Google Maps V2 and i'm drawing on it delivery route received from external GPX file, device path, device current location, and location of delivery points. Thing is that it works most of the time... 
Error that i get (when it's not working) is next:

```
    03-16 20:48:37.811: I/dalvikvm(16510): threadid=30: stack overflow on call to Lmaps/t/bx;.d:FLLL
    03-16 20:48:37.811: I/dalvikvm(16510):   method requires 40+20+0=60 bytes, fp is 0x60223318 (24 left)
    03-16 20:48:37.811: I/dalvikvm(16510):   expanding stack end (0x60223300 to 0x60223000)
    03-16 20:48:37.811: I/dalvikvm(16510): Shrank stack (to 0x60223300, curFrame is 0x60226e54)
    03-16 20:48:37.821: D/gralloc(16510): unmap_buffer: Successfully unmapped 0xa5000 bytes at address 0x60416000, SharedFd=89, map_count = 3
    03-16 20:48:37.821: D/gralloc(16510): unmap_buffer: Successfully unmapped 0xa5000 bytes at address 0x604bb000, SharedFd=96, map_count = 2
    03-16 20:48:37.881: W/dalvikvm(16510): threadid=30: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409f61f8)

    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1827
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.bx.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.bx.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
    03-16 20:32:23.471: E/AndroidRuntime(16283):    at maps.t.cg.a(Unknown Source)
```

Below is code example that generate problem.

UpdateMap method is called only once in onCreate method of Activity. Inside UpdateMap is DrawUserLocationOnMap call. I am opened for any suggestions.

UpdateMap method:

```
private void UpdateMap() {
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    int i = 0;

    // GPS COORDINATES RECEIVED FROM GPX FILE
    PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    LatLng initialCameraPosition = null;

    for (GpxTrackModel trackModel : ProviderUtility.GpxProvider.GpxTracks) {
        for (GpxTrackCoordinateModel coorModel : trackModel.getTrackCoordinates()) {
            if (i == 0)
                initialCameraPosition = new LatLng(coorModel.getLatitude(), coorModel.getLongitude());

            pOptions.add(new LatLng(coorModel.getLatitude(), coorModel.getLongitude()));
            i++;
        }

        // ADDING DESTINATION MARKERS (LAST LOCATION IN TRACK SEGMENT)
        MarkerOptions mOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        mOptions.draggable(false);

        GpxTrackCoordinateModel model = trackModel.getTrackCoordinates().get(trackModel.getTrackCoordinates().size() - 1);
        mOptions.position(new LatLng(model.getLatitude(), model.getLongitude()));
        mOptions.title(trackModel.getName());

        map.addMarker(mOptions).showInfoWindow();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(initialCameraPosition, 14));


        DrawUserLocationOnMap();

    }
    pOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    map.addPolyline(pOptions);

}
```

DrawUserLocationOnMap method:

```
PolylineOptions recordedPOptions = null;
MarkerOptions userLocation = null;

private void DrawUserLocationOnMap() {

    // RECORDED GPS DATA WITH GREEN LINE
    if (recordedPOptions == null)
        recordedPOptions = new PolylineOptions();

    // ADDING SAVED USER GPS COORDINATES FROM DATABASE AND DRAWING PATH
    ArrayList<GPSTrackingModel> list = ProviderUtility.GPSTrackingProvider.GetGPSCoordinates(false);
    for (GPSTrackingModel recordedGps : list)
        recordedPOptions.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(recordedGps.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(recordedGps.getLongitude())));

    recordedPOptions.color(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
    map.addPolyline(recordedPOptions);



    // ADDING CURRENT LOCATION MARKER
    GPSTrackingModel lastPosition = ProviderUtility.GPSTrackingProvider.GetLastCoordinate();
    if (lastPosition != null && lastPosition.getLatitude() != null
            && !lastPosition.getLatitude().equals("")
            && lastPosition.getLongitude() != null
            && !lastPosition.getLongitude().equals("")) {

        LatLng lp = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lastPosition.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(lastPosition.getLongitude()));

        if (userLocation == null) {
            userLocation = new MarkerOptions();

            userLocation.draggable(false);

            userLocation.position(lp);
            userLocation.title("My current location");
            userLocation.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.currentlocation));
            map.addMarker(userLocation);
        } else
            userLocation.position(lp);

        float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        if (zoom < 14)
            zoom = 14;
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lp, zoom));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To force error, i've added loop that calls DrawUserLocationOnMap() method every 200ms. After 4-5 seconds it crashed.

Comment: You might consider pasting an actual stack trace.

Comment: Temporary i cant reproduce error, since i uninstalled app and cleared logcat. I will as soon as error occurs again.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have added stacktrace.

Comment: I used the wrong google map apis key. It stop forced close after change to new apis key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by addressing some issues with your code, and hope that one of them is what is tripping up the Maps V2 library.

1. Do not call `animateCamera()` multiple times inside of a loop. Your users will get dizzy. Please call it once at the end.
2. Do not keep re-adding the same markers in the same positions, as your code is doing by virtue of you calling it a few dozen times ("every 200ms. After 4-5 seconds it crashed") for presumably the same model data, as that either is invalid production code (if you really do that) or an invalid test (if this is purely an artifact of how you forced the crash).

If those do not help, slowly start commenting out portions of your code, until you can narrow down precisely what is triggering the infinite recursion. I was hoping that the stack trace might show specifically where in your code the problem was triggered, but that did not work out.

Comment: Thank you, i have moved animate Camera from for loop, that was unintended mistake. 
However, as far as i can see, all markers are added only once since UpdateMap method is called only once, and userLocation marker in DrawUserLocationOnMap method only changes location after it is initialized.

The only thing that is suspicious to me is adding _recordedPOptions_ Polyline over and over again for same data model. I've commented this part of code and so far so good. 

So, conclusion would be that i should not adding two identical LatLng  to the same PolylineOptions more then once?

Comment: @helionprime: "all markers are added only once since UpdateMap method is called only once" -- no, it is being called "every 200ms", for "4-5 seconds". Hence, it is being called at least 20-25 times. "The only thing that is suspicious to me is adding recordedPOptions Polyline over and over again for same data model" -- you shouldn't be adding *anything* to the map "over and over again for the same data model". "So, conclusion would be that i should not adding two identical LatLng to the same PolylineOptions more then once?" -- AFAIAC, you should not add "two identical LatLng", period.

Comment: Oh god ok i got it...i suppose you have'nt read my code to the details, but that's something i understand. I respect you and your exeprience and i'll accept your answer. 

P.S. UpdateMap method is truly called only once. _To force error, i've added loop that calls DrawUserLocationOnMap() method every 200ms_ so everything is fine except recordedPOptions Polyline.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what was happening here. 
Thanks to @CommonsWare.

In DrawUserLocationOnMap() method i have for loop that add LatLng objects to recordedPOptions polyline. The thing is that *ProviderUtility.GPSTrackingProvider.GetGPSCoordinates(false)* returns all recorded coordinates that user/device visited. This method returns new (just recorder) coordinates and old, already drawn coordinates. My mistake was here, i was adding LatLng for the same old coordinates over and over again. That caused StackOverflow error. Now i have modified this part of DrawUserLocationOnMap() to add only new coordinates.