# java.lang.StackOverflowError in Google Play Services Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've noticed an increase in the number of StackOverflow crashes in my app which all seem to point back to Google Play Services Maps.  I am currently using version 15.0.1 (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1) - but this started about two weeks ago when I was still using 15.0.0.  There are several crashes, but they all result in StackOverflows when dealing with Hashmaps or Arrays from the Maps code (which is obfuscated).  Some examples of the crashes (I just copied the stack traces to the point where it goes to the obfuscated maps code):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB
   at java.util.HashMap.remove(HashMap.java:617)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685021@12.6.85 (040306-197041431):29)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
   at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.(ArrayList.java:551)
   at java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:548)
   at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.(Collections.java:953)
   at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:952)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.i.iterator(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685002@12.6.85 (000304-197041431):25)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:826)
   at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:813)
   at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:436)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):17)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at java.util.HashMap.removeEntryForKey(HashMap.java:597)
   at java.util.HashMap.remove(HashMap.java:584)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.e.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685023@12.6.85 (040400-197041431):29)


Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
   at java.util.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:170)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.i.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):9)
```

I also have a number of other crashes directly inside the obfuscated maps code.

Some other information:  the maps are not inside the main flow of my app, so it is only used by about 8% of my users - around 200 or so calls a day.  Today is by far the worst with 62 crashes affecting 13 users - two days ago it was 42 crashes and most other days I have zero crashes.

Operating system versions affected: 7.0, 6.0.1, 4.4.2, 7.1.1, 4.1.2, 5.1, 4.3

Devices: Samsung, Sony, Lenovo, Moto E3 (whatever that is) and a Huawei.

Any help or pointers would be useful!

Comment: Are you calling the code you mentioned recursively?  If so, what ends the recursion?

Comment: No.  I forgot to mention that the code hasn't changed in probably about a year.  I just show a map view and then sometimes draw markers on it or sometimes clear it.  There is definitely no recursion anywhere in my own code.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454258/2299040

Comment: Try to use map and zoom in right at the center of the London (I'm not joking). I had same issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691006/is-there-a-workaround-fix-to-these-google-maps-v2-stackoverflowerror-crashes